# JasperReports Server 4.5.0-0 Tutorials

Tags: jasper-reports, report, jasperserver

I have been looking around for some good tutorials on the JasperReports Server. I managed to find an installation, user and admin guide but these are for the older versions of JasperReports Server like 3.7, 4.0 or 4.2.

Any good links to tutorials or free guides on how to install, administer and use the most recent release, 4.5.0-0 are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are docs bundled right into the JasperReports Server [download](http://jasperforge.org/website/jasperserverwebsite/JSJA%20Website/js_download.html?header=project&target=jasperserver). The docs are downloadable separately from the same page. It includes several things that you're looking for:

```
$ ls -1 ./jasperreports-server-cp-4.5.0-docs 
JasperReports-Server-CP-Install-Guide.pdf
JasperReports-Server-CP-Source-Build-Guide.pdf
JasperReports-Server-CP-User-Guide.pdf
JasperReports-Server-Web-Services-Guide.pdf
Jaspersoft-OLAP-CP-User-Guide.pdf
Mondrian-3.0-Technical-Guide.pdf
```

I don't know why the Community Edition does not include an Admin Guide. You could download the commercial edition of JRS from the jaspersoft.com site. That includes an Admin Guide. There are lots of [samples](http://www.jaspersoft.com/getting-started) which you might consider tutorials on the .com site as well.

Comment: Thanks mdahlman. I however did not find the admin guide on this link. http://www.jaspersoft.com/thanks-download-30-day Am I looking in the wrong place perhaps?